# JPA design for serialized entities

Tags: jpa, design-patterns, openjpa

I'm looking for input into a design approach.  I have a requirement to serialize an entity,  send it to a remote client that does not have a JPA client, get it back and then update the database.

I have the first three portions working fine.  My questions is the approach for saving the entity after it is returned from the client.

My current approach is:

1. Retreive it again from the database so it is managed
2. Check the version to prevent concurrent modifications
3. Copy the fields from the serialized entity to the managed one
4. Save the managed entity using merge()

I would appreciate your input on several aspects

1. Is there a better overall approach to saving the modified entity?
2. When copying the fields a simple field assignment is not recognized as a modification but a setter is a change

   2a.  `this.name = modified.getName()` results in no update statement
   sent to the database

   2b. `this.setName(modified.getName())` results in an update
3. Collections of children are throwing `ClassCastException`.  How can I successfully update (add/remove/change) a collection?

This is with openjpa 2.4.1 if it is relevant to the discussion.

Thanks for your input!

Tim

Comment: When you say "serialize" do you mean Java's built-in object serialization or serializing to XML, JSON, protobuf. .etc and marshaling the object as a payload over a transport such as HTTP, JMS, etc?

Comment: A mixture of both.  I'm using Eclipse ECF to make transferring the object state from server to client.  How it does this is transparent to my application.    Internally ECF likely uses Java built in serialization.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that I think you would want to minimize the amount of code you have to write.    I think you want to AVOID writing a statement for each field you want serialized or writing a call for each subentity.

Towards that end, I think you want to give all your serialized entity fields the same name as in the managed one.   If you need the field serialized with a different name use @JsonProperty.

Then you might want to look into using a "deep copy" utility to avoid having to explicitly copy all the fields one by one.